# XSLT-разработки

Tags: сервер, xslt

День добрый.
Как начать изучать и тестировать преобразования xml/xslt на локальном компьютере? Денвер и EasyPHP отказываются понимать xslt как таковой. ОС - Windows 7. Может, посоветуете сборку, чтобы не сидеть ночами с настройкой Апача и т.п.

Comment: [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads) + [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), если Vagrant его потребует + любой образ с пометкой LAMP-stack [отсюда](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads)

Есть еще [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/), но он тесно завязан с ядром линукс, поэтому на винде уже сам докер придется запускать в виртуалке, что вряд ли сделает этот вариант предпочтительным.

**upd** увидел слово "сборка". Попробуйте OpenServer и WAMP, это, кажется, пара лучших решений сейчас.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ.Попробую все варианты. WAMP не захотел вставать из-за .NET dll какой-то :(

Comment: @Роман Жуков, это значит, что ему нужен .NET Framework для работы, эта штука необходима для многих приложений, лучше скачайте, даже если не собираетесь WAMP ставить: http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: А что, уже php не заводиться из-за .NET? Или мускуль:). Как же оно тогда у меня на линуксе работает:)

Comment: @KoVadim, оболочка графическая не заводится, видимо.

Answer (score 1):

Плохо понимаю, что у вас отказывается работать на Денвере.
Установил денвер, создал два файла.

Файл index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<user>
    <name>Andrey</name>
    <lastname>Pilipenko</lastname>
</user>
```

Второй файл index.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink">

    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/" />
        <br />
        <xsl:value-of select="/user/name" />
        <br />
        <xsl:value-of select="/user/lastname" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Через браузер открываю страницу http://localhost/index.xml и получаю страницу с обработанными данными в том формате html, который прописан в файле xsl. Все.

Если взглянуть на расшифровку аббревиатуры то становиться понятно, что xslt это стили для отрисовки xml данных.

Для более углубленного изучения лучше почитать http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt